# Android support library v4 RemoteControlClient dependecy error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-build, cyanogenmod

I get these errors when I try to compile my cyanogenmod rom
(12.1)

```
frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/media/TransportMediator.java:190: error: cannot access RemoteControlClient
        return mController != null ? mController.getRemoteControlClient() : null;
                                                ^
  class file for android.media.RemoteControlClient not found
frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/media/TransportMediator.java:240: error: cannot access OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener
            mController.refreshState(mCallbacks.onIsPlaying(),
                       ^
  class file for android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener not found
Note: frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEventCompat.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Do you know what can I do to fix it? It's related to Support Libraries as v4 library searches for current RemoteControlClient class that I've found in the SDK in *media/* folder.

It's the original android source code so I really don't understand why I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-downloading the source fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you know why? Re-downloading seems to take quite a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Class `android.support.v4.media.TransportMediator` now deprecated.

From Level: **25.2.0** To Level: **26.0.0-alpha1**, since **2017.03.24 13:03**

Hope this link can help:
https://github.com/square/assertj-android/issues/221

And I just add the following sentence to dependencies

> implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

You have to include support library in gradle file like this 
    compile '`com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0`'

I would also recommend you to add following library as they are often use interchangably.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Are you talking about adding  
`import com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0  
import com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0  
import com.android.support:design:23.0.1`  
in _system/frameworks/support/v4/build.gradle_ file? It's very strange because it should work without importing! It's the **native android source**!

Comment: I got the same error when `make update-api`. I also use the native android source and I think I did not change any code. I am compiling AOSP 6.-.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenJDK 7. What is strange is that before I build successfully and even flashed the rom into nexus 5.